# SQL Trigger to update row

Tags: sql, triggers

I need a SQL trigger that would zero pad a cell whenever its inserted or updated. Was curious if its best practice to append two strings together like I'm doing in the update command. Is this be best way to do it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER PadColumnTenCharsInserted ON Table
AFTER INSERT
AS

DECLARE
    @pad_characters VARCHAR(10),
    @target_column NVARCHAR(255)

SET @pad_characters = '0000000000'
SET @target_column = 'IndexField1'

IF UPDATE(IndexField1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table
    SET IndexField1 = RIGHT(@pad_characters + IndexField1, 10)
END

GO
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your padding code looks fine.

Instead of updating every row in the table like this:

```
    UPDATE Table
```

update just the row that triggered the trigger:

```
    UPDATE updated
```

Also, you've still got some extraneous code -- everything involving @target_column. And it looks like you're not sure if this is an INSERT trigger or an UPDATE trigger. I see `AFTER INSERT` and `IF UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:

1. What are you doing with @target_column?  You declare it and set it with a column name, but then you never use it.  If you intend to use the variable in your subsequent SQL statements, you may need to wrap the statements in an EXECUTE() or use sp_executesql().
2. The syntax "UPDATE Table..." is OK for your update statement assuming that "Table" is the name of the table you are updating.  What seems to be missing is a filter of some kind.  Or did you really intend for that column to be updated for every row in the whole table?
   One way to handle this would be to declare another variable and set it with the PK of the row that is updated, then use a where clause to limit the update to just that row.  Something like this:

   DECLARE @id int

   SELECT @id = Record_ID FROM INSERTED

   -- body of your trigger here

   WHERE Record_ID = @id
3. I like your padding code.  It looks good to me.